# return default value when user not input

Tags: go

return default value when user not input field
var (
notes ='this will be default'
)

```
qapi := `
UPDATE custom_param SET param_value = $1, start_date = $2, end_date = $3, status = $4 `enter code here` WHERE param_name = 'default-password'
RETURNING param_value, start_date, end_date, status, notes; 
`
// insrt into master_param
sqlError := tx.QueryRowContext(ctx, qapi, request.Value, request.StartDate, request.EndDate, request.Status, request.Notes).Scan(
    &value,
    &startDate,
    &endDate,
    &status,
    &notes,
)
queryInsertNotes := `insert `
if request.Notes != "" {
    notes = request.Notes
}

if sqlError != nil {
    log.Println("SQL Error on ReadApplication on UpdateScheduleMaintenance", sqlError)
    tx.Rollback()
    return schedule, sqlError
}

err = tx.Commit()
if err != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
    return schedule, err
}
```

return default notes when user not inputs any notes

Comment: What do you mean with return? This is running inside a function and you want to return a string or you want to pass that to the SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this, haven't tested the code but you get the idea.

```
notes := "this will be default"
if request.Notes != "" {
    notes = request.Notes
}

qapi := `
UPDATE custom_param SET param_value = $1, start_date = $2, end_date = $3, status = $4, notes = $4 WHERE param_name = 'default-password'
RETURNING param_value, start_date, end_date, status, notes; 
`
// insrt into master_param
sqlError := tx.QueryRowContext(ctx, qapi, request.Value, request.StartDate, request.EndDate, request.Status, notes).Scan(
    &value,
    &startDate,
    &endDate,
    &status,
    &notes,
)


if sqlError != nil {
    log.Println("SQL Error on ReadApplication on UpdateScheduleMaintenance", sqlError)
    tx.Rollback()
    return schedule, sqlError
}

err = tx.Commit()
if err != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
    return schedule, err
}
```

Comment: I've done that before but the rows in the database haven't changed

Comment: Check everything again, what I posted is correct, you may have an error somewhere else.